# How effective are adaptive shields against burst fire?

Tags: borderlands-2

Adaptive shields will alter itself to resist the element that last hit the shield.  How fast is this effect?  For instance, if I shoot someone wearing an adaptive shield with a corrosive shotgun with 10 pellets, will the shield take full damage for the entire shot, or will it take full damage for the first pellet and then reduce the damage for the other 9 pellets?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you shoot an enemy with a shotgun, typically only one damage number pops up. So just because of just that I would assume that they take full damage from the shot.

On larger enemies however, if you are far away and the bullets are spread out enough it could pop up 2 or more numbers for damage depending on how large the shotgun's spread is and the distance the bullets traveled. Not sure if that will work the same in this case.

Comment: I thought the numbers were always bunched up together so it doesn't end up spamming the player?  I've noticed shooting something many times with a SMG and only seeing one number.

Comment: The first part would be right, I guess you could always hit an enemy with one pellet and then hit it with more pellets and see if the damage per pellet is the same. I've never seen that effect with SMG's before though.